# Symfony BinaryFileResponse set filename

Tags: php, file, symfony, controller

Is it possible to set a custom filename when the file is returned by a Symfony2 controller using a BinaryFileResponse response?

Comment: use `$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', $filename));`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes. The `BinaryFileResponse` class has a method `setContentDisposition()` that takes the file name as the second argument.

The first argument is the way the file should be delivered. It can be `ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT` (or just the string `"attachment"`) if the file should be offered for downloading, or `ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE` (or `"inline"`) if you want the file to be shown in the browser (you may want to do this with images, for example).

A full code example:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag;

$response = new BinaryFileResponse('/path/to/myfile');
$response->setContentDisposition(
    ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    'file_name.txt'
);
```