# Open pdf from server path in Symfony3

Tags: symfony

I would like to open the pdf file in the window browser but I have "The file "\\servername\20\2016080.pdf" does not exist" 
If I copy this path in a browser, it's work.

Edit: I have found in the logs

> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException: "The file "\\servername\20\2016080.pdf" does not exist" at C:\wamp64\www\his\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File.php line 37

Thank you.

```
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($result = $ServerModel->getDocument($request-> get('id'));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
return $response;
```

Comment: have you already tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28920003/2270041 ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need a [RedirectResponse](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#redirecting) instead?

Comment: I already tried it, I have the same error.
No, I don't need it.
thank you.

Comment: is this a typo or a copy paste error? `$request-> get('id')`

Comment: Copy past the path also no works and I don't understand typo.

Comment: where is the file located? Can you share the real absolute path of the file? Could be the first double slash be the problem?

Comment: It located in a server. That is the real absolute path, I just replace the real servername. I don't think the double slash is the probleme because it escape all the slash.

at File ->__construct ('\\\\servername\\20\\2016080.pdf') 
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse.php at line 94.
I edited my post.

Comment: seems a remote address (samba or some other protocols), that your browser can resolve BUT is not a real path that the server can handle. Hope this can help on investigation. If is so you  should mount the folder on the server file system...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using symfony 3.2 or later (which you should be), you can use the new `file` helper to serve binary files.

[from the symfony docs](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-file-controller-helper)

```
$pdfPath = $this->getParameter('dir.downloads').'/sample.pdf';

return $this->file($pdfPath);
```

how you go about getting the path of the file may differ depending on your implementation.  But if its a straight `SplFileInfo::` object [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) then you can just use:

```
$file->getPathname();
```

The file helper will automagically do much of heavy lifting for you.

Make sure the file is accessible, either by a route or by an un-firewalled path.

Comment: your path is not accessible by the looks of it.  Whats the actual path of the file?

Comment: I don't have access.

Comment: if you dont have access how do you think you can download it?

Comment: I don't have access to the server but I have access to the network share.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
* @Route("/show-pdf", name="show-pdf")
*/
public function showPdf(Request $request) {

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    $pdf = file_get_contents('path/to/file.pdf');

    return new Response($pdf, 200, [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="file.pdf"'
    ]);

}
```